# Почему не видно кнопки?

Tags: yii2

Установил композером  Imperavi Redactor Widget для Yii 2 как описано вот [здесь](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget/blob/master/README_RU.md)

Виджет установился, можно править текст и т.д., но не хватает некоторых кнопок, например для изображений, а она ведь вроде по умолчанию задана. Как быть, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: некоторые "кнопки" у редактора подключаются в качестве плагинов, почитайте документацию подробней

Comment: Спасибо, кнопки добавил путем добавления параметров imageUpload и fileUpload, но теперь проблема - не грузит в папку изображение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> а она ведь вроде по умолчанию задана
>   нет

Надо задать урл куда фото слать, тогда отобразится, например:

```
echo \vova07\imperavi\Widget::widget([
'selector' => '#my-textarea-id',
'settings' => [
    'imageUpload' => Url::to(['/default/image-upload']) //я вот про это
]]);
```